# Вернуть n массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив данных в котором может находиться не ограниченное кол-во объектов. 
Хочу написать функцию которая будет возвращать каждые 10 элементов массива. То есть первые 10 потом следующие 10 и т.д. По сути это обычная пагинация.

Мой пример не корректно работает, точнее возвращает но не совсем то что мне необходимо.

```js
const demoDMS = [
  {id: 1, quantity: 6436},
  {id: 2, quantity: 3131},
  {id: 3, quantity: 23},
  {id: 4, quantity: 123},
  {id: 5, quantity: 3213},
  {id: 6, quantity: 322},
  {id: 7, quantity: 55},
  {id: 8, quantity: 334},
  {id: 9, quantity: 13},
  {id: 10, quantity: 1414},
  {id: 11, quantity: 22},
  {id: 12, quantity: 23},
  {id: 13, quantity: 424},
  {id: 14, quantity: 3232},
  {id: 15, quantity: 525},
  {id: 16, quantity: 222},
  {id: 17, quantity: 123},
  {id: 18, quantity: 3213},
  {id: 19, quantity: 4124},
  {id: 20, quantity: 132},
  {id: 21, quantity: 1234},
  {id: 22, quantity: 5325},
  {id: 23, quantity: 6462},
  {id: 24, quantity: 6472},
  {id: 25, quantity: 232},
  {id: 26, quantity: 5346},
  {id: 27, quantity: 5464},
  {id: 28, quantity: 12362},
  {id: 29, quantity: 8657},
  {id: 30, quantity: 9587}
];
function rebaseDMSelements(page) {
  const count = 10;
  let data = demoDMS
    .filter((i, index) => (page * count > index + 1 && index + 1 < page * count))
  if (page * count < demoDMS.length) {
    this.rebaseDMSelements(page + 1)
  }
  console.log(`page number: ` + page, 'elements: ' + data.length)
}

rebaseDMSelements(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно получать страницы строго по порядку, то можно использовать генератор:

```js
const demoDMS = [
  {id: 1, quantity: 6436},
  {id: 2, quantity: 3131},
  {id: 3, quantity: 23},
  {id: 4, quantity: 123},
  {id: 5, quantity: 3213},
  {id: 6, quantity: 322},
  {id: 7, quantity: 55},
  {id: 8, quantity: 334},
  {id: 9, quantity: 13},
  {id: 10, quantity: 1414},
  {id: 11, quantity: 22},
  {id: 12, quantity: 23},
  {id: 13, quantity: 424},
  {id: 14, quantity: 3232},
  {id: 15, quantity: 525},
  {id: 16, quantity: 222},
  {id: 17, quantity: 123},
  {id: 18, quantity: 3213},
  {id: 19, quantity: 4124},
  {id: 20, quantity: 132},
  {id: 21, quantity: 1234},
  {id: 22, quantity: 5325},
  {id: 23, quantity: 6462},
  {id: 24, quantity: 6472},
  {id: 25, quantity: 232},
  {id: 26, quantity: 5346},
  {id: 27, quantity: 5464},
  {id: 28, quantity: 12362},
  {id: 29, quantity: 8657},
  {id: 30, quantity: 9587}
];

function * getPage() {
  const PAGESIZE = 10;
  let currentPage = 0;
  while (true) {
    let curPage = demoDMS.slice(currentPage * PAGESIZE, (currentPage + 1) * PAGESIZE)
    currentPage++;
    yield curPage;
  }
}

let page = getPage();
console.log(page.next().value);
console.log(page.next().value);
console.log(page.next().value);
```

Если не по порядку, то тоже можно, но немного сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

> Мой пример ... возвращает но не совсем то

Ваш пример вообще ничего не возвращает. Обратите внимание на отсутствие в коде слова `return`.

Это два раза повторенное условие с переставленными левой и правой частями

```
(page * count > index + 1 && index + 1 < page * count)
```

что проверяет?

Comment: Если честно сам не понял зачем. А вообще у меня в коде оно возвращает элементы) для наглядности я вывел результат в консоль.

Comment: По сути надо было написать вот так `demoDMS.filter((i, index) => ((page - 1) * cnt > index + 1 && index + 1 < page * cnt))` но оно все равно не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой пример довольно просто. Переписав немного формулу.

```js
const demoDMS = [{
    id: 1,
    quantity: 6436
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 3131
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    quantity: 23
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    quantity: 123
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    quantity: 3213
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    quantity: 322
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    quantity: 55
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    quantity: 334
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    quantity: 13
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    quantity: 1414
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    quantity: 22
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    quantity: 23
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    quantity: 424
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    quantity: 3232
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    quantity: 525
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    quantity: 222
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    quantity: 123
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    quantity: 3213
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    quantity: 4124
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    quantity: 132
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    quantity: 1234
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    quantity: 5325
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    quantity: 6462
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    quantity: 6472
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    quantity: 232
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    quantity: 5346
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    quantity: 5464
  },
  {
    id: 28,
    quantity: 12362
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    quantity: 8657
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    quantity: 9587
  }
];

function rebaseDMSelements(page) {
  const count = demoDMS.length; //всего записей
  const cnt = 10; //сколько отображаем сначала
  const cnt_page = Math.ceil(count / cnt); //кол-во страниц

  let data = demoDMS.filter((i, index) => ((page - 1) * cnt <= index && index + 1 <= page * cnt));
  if (page !== cnt_page) {
    rebaseDMSelements(page + 1)
  }
  console.log('page: ' + page, 'count: ' + data.length);
}

rebaseDMSelements(1);
```